# Web resource changes doesn't reflect in Cordova App while using Mobilefirst web encryption feature

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am following exactly the steps that appear in the official documentation on this subject.

[Tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/pt-br/foundation/8.0/application-development/cordova-apps/securing-apps/)

This works fine for me, but once the code is encrypted and I want to make changes, these are not reflected. In order to see the changes reflected I must always `mfpdev app webupdate`

Comment: What you mean by the changes are not reflected ? Can you elaborate the problem which you are facing ??

Comment: I'm working an app with cordova and for example, I add a comment line, something as simple as a console.log and it is not reflected in my app. @VittalPai

Comment: Even without web encryption that changes wont reflect automatically until and unless you run the command `cordova prepare` or `mfpdev app webupdate`

Comment: It is recommended to enable web encryption feature once you done with the development where there is no more code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/pt-br/foundation/8.0/application-development/cordova-apps/securing-apps/) to encrypt the web resources of cordova packages.

> The best time to complete this procedure is after finishing your app development and are ready to deploy the app.

If you still wish to do changes after encryption, you need to go through whole process as mentioned in the [tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/pt-br/foundation/8.0/application-development/cordova-apps/securing-apps/).

Comment: I did, but my changes still do not work, if I finish the app and then I need to make changes, updates or resolve bugs, how could I see the changes?

Comment: @sioesi  As I said above, you need to go through whole  process mentioned in the tutorial.